# Finding Missing Values in datasets

Tags: machine-learning

I just want your help over a issue, about how I come to know that there are missing values specially in big data sets i.e. which columns having missing values and whose not?

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on how the dataset is stored (if it’s at rest as a disk file), or what interface is it accessible through (SQL, graph query, etc).

If it’s a “plain file” like CSV, HDF, an Octave/Matlab matrix, then use whatever scripting tool you’re comfortable with to iterate the rows and check for missing values. If it’s an SQL dump, you can load it into SQLite or sql server and select for missing values. You could even use an SQL parser to directly report missing values from the SQL dump, since there’s really no need to persist it into a database.

If it’s live data behind an API, you can use the api to query the data for missing values – if the api supports such queries. Otherwise, use the api to export (dump) the entire data set, and query it at rest as in preceding paragraph. If the dataset doesn’t have indices that allow finding missing data, then you’ll expect the query to take long, and possibly have performance impact on the service that provides the data – act with care and understand the exact consequences of what you’re about to do.

Answer (score 0):

This gives number of missing values of each column. Use your pandas dataframe instead of `train`.

```
train.isnull().sum()
```

Otherwise you can use `train.info()` or `train.describe()` for complete information or description of data, which also shows missing values in each column.

Answer (score 0):

Number of missing values for entire dataset `df.isnull().sum().sum()`